# Dynamic Return Type

Tags: apex

Is it possible to create a method that will return any sObject type?

Why?

I want to create a method that combines DML operations, but the initial method that is called should be able to return any sObject type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always create a method to return a `SObject`. Something as below:

```
public SObject mySObject() {
    if(condition) {
        return new Account();
    } else {
        return new Contact();
    }
}
```

It will though depend on how you want to utilize it from your calling context. You can always get the `SObjectType` in your calling context and take actions accordingly. E.g.,

```
SObject s = mySobject();
system.debug(s.getSObjectType());
// execute other code based on type
```

Comment: even better is to return a List<SObject> so caller can work with collection idioms

Comment: @cropredy Agreed. This was more of a direct answer to the question itself, definitely always scope of improvements/refinement based on actual requirements.

Comment: You can also use `instanceof` (e.g. `if(s instanceof Account)`) or a [switch statement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm)

Comment: @IllusiveBrian That's true. Many different ways of doing that. This was mostly a sample/approach, which is always open for refinement in actual implementation.